# How to add multiple command with DOCKER to run FASTAPI & CRON job togather

Tags: python, linux, docker, cron, fastapi

I have a docker file that can run fast API and CRON jobs scheduler separately very well. But I want to run them together how can I do it?

Folder Structure:
[image]

Docker File

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron vim

WORKDIR    /opt/oracle
RUN        apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 wget unzip \
            && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
            && unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
            && rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
            && cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* \
            && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *README *jar uidrvci genezi adrci \
            && echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf \
            && ldconfig

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


COPY . .

COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
COPY hello.py /app/hello.py
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

EXPOSE 8000

# run process of container
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

Comment: Run two containers, overriding the command part of the second one to run the cron daemon; maybe `docker run -d your-image crond -f`.

Comment: Why don't you run the cron jobs inside fastapi application itself if they are ofcourse related to the application using [fastapi-utilities](https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-utilities/)